# Disable snap-back when scrolling in Interface Builder (Xcode 5)

Tags: interface-builder, xcode5, uistoryboard, usability

I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug (it feels like a bug), but ever since I upgraded to Xcode 5, whenever I scroll all the way to the right of my storyboard canvas area, the view snaps back to the start (or far left).

I have googled this but to know avail. I wondered if anyone else is experiencing this issue, and if so, how do you deal with it. In other words, I'm looking to disable it, or some kind of a workaround.

Comment: Yup, I have this problem too. Very annoying feature of Xcode and I can't find an option to turn it off.

Comment: @Rick I guess out of the hundreds of thousands of Xcode users out there, we are the only two experiencing this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update Xcode to Version 5.1.1 and the issue is resolved.